# Does anonymous function requires lambda format (println ex)?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, lambda, anonymous-function, println

I got to know recently that Anonymous function

1. is given in the form of: function body that follows argument Lambda
   (=>)
2. and it has no name
3. is used once in the code

So, you don't have to add a complete function to do this but rather, you can put the function body in use directly in your code (main function).

I read that in spark, "println" statement is always considered anonymous method for the following reasons:

1. println statement is considered a function body
2. Moreover, it wasn't added to a method with a name but was rather
   used directly in the main class.
3. Also, it was used once in the code.

Ex: 
Before converting to anonymous
[click to view pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0XMv.png)

After converting to anonymous
[click to view pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRxst.png)

However, my question is what if the Lambda function wasn't used.. will println be considered as anonymous function still as shown in the ex below?

main question Ex:
[click to view pic3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23hY4.png)

Comment: Friendly advice: I'm pretty sure most people won't be thrilled about the screenshots of IDE. Why not posting code in code blocks?

Answer (score 0):

println is a function, but it is not an anonymous function since it has a name.

Comment: `println` is not a function at all, it's a method

Comment: @RaphaelRoth that's an argument of semantics which I don't beleive is super relevant here. Methods can act as functions via eta-expansion anyway.